# Set iterator got invalidated?

Tags: c++, stl

there is something I don't really understand. Why in the following code I have different value of *it? Before loop it is 1, and after loop it is 5

```
set <int> my_set{3,1,4,2,5};
set<int>::iterator it = my_set.begin();
cout << "beginning of set  " << *it << endl;

for(; it != my_set.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
    
cout << "Beginning of set  " << *it << endl;
```

Comment: Because you modify it at `++it`. After the loop `it == my_set.end();` Dereferencing it at that point, I believe, is undefined behavior.

Comment: What do you think `++it` does?

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah, I see now

Comment: Also note that dereferencing `it` after the loop when it is equal to the value returned by `my_set.end()` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end "This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior."

Comment: *"Why in the following code I have different value of *it?"* Because you have a different value of `it`. Why did you think it would be the same as before the loop, when one purpose of your loop is to change `it`?

Comment: Oleg, I do hope you are doing well.